# Visual Studio 2010 sometimes build configuration folder name is only first word, sometimes its the whole string. How does one control this?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, configuration, build, output

I really want (it would be much better) to have all versions of 'Release' build configurations map into the common '..\Release' folder as it does for solution (**a**) below. However I do not know how to control this and right now all new build configurations are behaving link (**b**) below? Where the output folder name is exactly the full name of the build configuration.... sigh..... Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to provide...

I have one solution that has build configurations as this:

**solution (a):**

- Debug
- Release
- Release (Static Link)

And another solution that has build configurations as this:

**solution (b):**

- Debug
- Release
- Release (ver. 2.0 with install)
- Release (ver. 2.0 no install)

Selecting and Rebuilding each configuration for solution (**a**) creates the following output folders (these are the actual folder names):

1. ..\Debug
2. ..\Release

Selecting and Rebuilding each configuration for solution (**b**) creates the following output folders (these are the actual folder names):

1. ..\Debug
2. ..\Release
3. ..\Release (ver. 2.0 with install)
4. ..\Release (ver. 2.0 no install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set the "Output path" under the "Build" tab of the project properties for whichever configuration is not acting as you want.

You can switch between project configurations on the top of the project properties window.